# Debian 10 VPS slow internet speed after long uptime

Tags: linux, debian, internet

I recently observed, that my VPS server running Debian 10 (mainly running nginx server and nodejs) have very slow internet connection after few months of uptime until I do full hard reboot.

Any ideas what can cause this behavior?

Before reboot:[image]

After reboot:[image]

Comment: unless you have something set up that extends and extends your nftables / iptables rules while you're running, and now you're running into RAM bandwidth and CPU limitiations when processing packets for and from the network: no idea. On what platform does that VPS run?

Comment: perhaps wading through the system logs could find something - bit difficult to debug since you have to wait months for the problem to manifest